# Explanation for legi and dilexi having different perfect stems?

Tags: etymology

Is there any explanation for why the perfect stem of lego is *legi*, but the stem for a word derived from it is *dilexi*? It seems that other related words like *adlegi* and *sublegi* follow the expected pattern.

Comment: Greek has traces of both aorists in ἐλέγην (passive; the active voice would have been formally identical to the imperfect, I expect) and ἔλεξα respectively in Homer and Attic preserves the sigmatic aorist in some compounds (bare λέγω is suppletive in the aorist), so this multitude of perfective forms as well as the inconsistent levelling is not unique to Latin. It might be interesting to see what Albanian does as the only other language to have reflexes of *\*leǵ-* (probably nothing visible).

Comment: Apparently it has been suggested that *diligo* as well as *intellego* and *neglego*, which also have *-lexi*, are from a different root *\*h₂leg-* 'to care for' (as supposedly in Greek ἀλέγω but not much else) that just had a sigmatic perfective, but De Vaan rejects that. If nothing else, the *-e-* in the *-lego* of the latter two suggests they're recent formations and uncompounded  *lego* 'to care for' is unattested.